# Proof for the Characteristic Path Length

Tags: graph-theory, online-resources

Where is there proof on the characteristic path length I have been looking online and can't seem to find any? I find the equation a lot however, I don't seem to find any actual proof is there a mathematical paper that can be referenced.

Comment: What do you want a proof of?

Comment: @MishaLavrov How the actual equation was derived?

Comment: I am asking what equation you're talking about.

Comment: This one $\frac{1}{q(q-1)}\sum_{l \in V} l_i$

Comment: Is that the same as $$\frac1{|V|(|V|-1)} \sum_{v \in V} \sum_{w \in V \setminus \{v\}} d(v, w)$$ where $d(v,w)$ is the distance from $v$ to $w$? It looks similar, but I don't know your $q$ or your $l_i$, and I don't know if you want the explanation of the double sum I quoted, or if you have a different idea of $l_i$ and want to know how it relates to the double sum.

Comment: Yes, I haven't really found any derivation of the equation...

Comment: I have tried to answer your question, but I am still not 100% sure that what I answered is what you were asking. I wish this interaction hadn't felt like pulling teeth to get more details out of you. All of them could have been included in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The formula
$$
\frac1{|V|(|V|-1)} \sum_{v \in V} \sum_{w \in V \setminus \{v\}} d(v, w)
$$
gives us the average of all distances between vertices in the graph. There are $|V|(|V|-1)$ pairs $(v,w)$ of distinct vertices; for each of them, the double sum has a $d(v,w)$ term. Then we divide by $|V|(|V|-1)$ terms to get the average.

For example, in a directed graph with three vertices $x,y,z$, this formula would give us
$$
  \frac{d(x,y) + d(x,z) + d(y,x) + d(y,z) + d(z,x) + d(z,y)}{6}.
$$
If the graph were undirected, then $d(v,w) = d(w,v)$ for every pair of vertices $v,w$. That doesn't make the formula wrong, but it makes it have redundant terms; we could simplify the average in that case to
$$
  \frac{2d(x,y) + 2d(x,z) + 2d(y,z)}{6} = \frac{d(x,y) + d(x,z) + d(y,z)}{3}.
$$
(Of course, in a $3$-vertex graph, all these distances are very boring, but that's not the point.)

The formula doesn't have a proof, as such, because it's the *definition* of characteristic path length. However, that definition is motivated by wanting to average all distances in the graph.